# How to track swift close button being clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am asked to put a tracker on the close button in a `viewController`, I shall not use `viewWillDisappear` and `deinit` since there could be some errors that dismiss the `view`, how do I programmatically track the close button and for example put an `onTap` on it to track whether it is clicked **MANUALLY** by user but not closed by errors?

I am using `UIKit` for programmatic layout, sorry if there's any inaccuracy I am new to Swift

Answer (score 2):

If the `close` button is a classic UIButton then you can do it like this:

```
closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeBtnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    
@objc func closeBtnTapped() {
    print("User tapped the close-button")
}
```

Comment: I cannot find the closeButton in this way, because I am using UIKit layout

Comment: Do you mean a storyboards?

Comment: @Choi I named it `closeButton` to be more clear, you name it however you want.